# How to get chart from data points (arrays) with inconsistent time intervals and chart.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, chart.js

I would like to display time based line charts with chart.js. The data is send via websocket as JSON:

```
{"sid":"eg.room06.temperatures.temp_1|avg|48h|now|100","series":[[1493198415233,21.4],[1493199364487,22.49],[1493201144363,21.97],[1493202824105,22.17],[1493204564473,22.38],[1493206324305,23.22],[1493208065142,23.39],[1493209786437,23.29],[1493211467193,23.05],[1493213248115,22.96],[1493214948390,23.08],[1493216828460,23.56],[1493268170194,19.03],[1493268589754,20.64],[1493270209957,20.4],[1493271949853,20.63],[1493273729827,20.92],[1493275649936,21.33],[1493277149966,21.57],[1493279129695,21.72],[1493280629731,22.23],[1493282310040,22.83],[1493284229704,22.82],[1493285930008,22.96],[1493287629860,22.7],[1493289330698,22.77],[1493290970948,23.15],[1493292690815,23.34],[1493294530805,23.53],[1493296151043,23.73],[1493298111710,23.74],[1493299651839,23.91],[1493301471857,24.15],[1493303152125,24.16],[1493304932038,24.03],[1493306652867,23.94],[1493356934754,20.26],[1493358474848,20.55],[1493360075050,21.08],[1493361834946,21.6],[1493363614864,21.99],[1493365434873,22.31],[1493367055112,22.75],[1493368855114,23.0],[1493370754724,23.08],[1493371055130,23.125],[1493371215233,23.125]],"cmd":"series"}
```

At first JSON.parse is used to get the required data. Within a loop the x- and y-values get separated.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
var timeIntX = [];
var valueY = [];
for (var i=0; i < obj.series.length; i++) {
    var valPair = obj.series[i];
    timeIntX.push(valPair[0]);
    valueY.push(valPair[1]);
}
```

timeIntX (epoch format):

```
1493199182012,1493199364487,1493201144363,1493202824105,1493204564473,1493206324305,1493208065142,1493209786437,1493211467193,1493213248115,1493214948390,1493216828460,1493268170194,1493268589754,1493270209957,1493271949853,1493273729827,1493275649936,1493277149966,1493279129695,1493280629731,1493282310040,1493284229704,1493285930008,1493287629860,1493289330698,1493290970948,1493292690815,1493294530805,1493296151043,1493298111710,1493299651839,1493301471857,1493303152125,1493304932038,1493306652867,1493356934754,1493358474848,1493360075050,1493361834946,1493363614864,1493365434873,1493367055112,1493368855114,1493370754724,1493371854699,1493371982012
```

valueY:

```
21.66,22.49,21.97,22.17,22.38,23.22,23.39,23.29,23.05,22.96,23.08,23.56,19.03,20.64,20.4,20.63,20.92,21.33,21.57,21.72,22.23,22.83,22.82,22.96,22.7,22.77,23.15,23.34,23.53,23.73,23.74,23.91,24.15,24.16,24.03,23.94,20.26,20.55,21.08,21.6,21.99,22.31,22.75,23,23.14,23.25,23.25
```

Now these arrays serve as X- and Y-data for the chart.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: timeIntX,
        datasets: [
        {
            label: "Temperatur Zimmer 1006",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: valueY,
            spanGaps: true,
        }]
    }
});
```

As script source I included Chart.js, moment.js and jquery.js. The following code exists in the html body:

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
```

The chart is displayed, but because of the different time intervals the data is not correctly scaled.
I know that there is the time scale option ([see Documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-scale)) but after a lot of tries I still don't know how to use it right.

Please ask if you need additional information. It would be great if you could help me.

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: What happens when you pass `options: { scales: { xAxes: [{ type: 'time'}]}}` to the constructor?

Comment: In this case the chart is not loaded and the .html file isn´t even listed at the Firefox dev-tools. I tried to add the options expression on different levels (within the main brackets and within `data: {...}`.

Comment: I forgot the comma after the closing bracket of `data`. Now the chart is not displayed but there is a white space where the chart should be.

Comment: Maybe you have to replace the numerical values with date objects to make it work? I'm not exactly sure how chart.js does it...

Comment: I tried it with converting by `new Date(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)` but it is the same result. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now found out how to solve my problem. The main issue was the construction of the array. Below you can see my new code. The raw data stay the same.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
var plotData = [];
for (var i=0; i < obj.series.length; i++) {
    plotData.push({'x': obj.series[i][0], 'y': obj.series[i][1]});
}
```

The following code shows the initialization of the chart. In the documentation you find the data formatting under [Scatter Line Charts](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-scatter-line-charts).

```
var chartData = {
    datasets: [{
        borderColor: 'orange',
        label: 'time chart',
        data: plotData,
        lineTension: 0.1,
    }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

window.myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
        title: { 
            display: true,
            text: "series1",
            fontSize: 30
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    tooltipFormat: 'h:mm:ss a'
                }
            }]
        }
    },
});
```

This setup works for me. Don´t forget the  tag in your HTML code and the reference to jquery.js, moment.js and chart.js.

I hope this answer can save some time.